# Undesired behavior: compiler skips figure onto the next page no matter what

Tags: floats, positioning, multicol

This one is driving me crazy, I really hope somebody can give me a hint about what's going on...

In this print-screen you can see the code compared to the compiled result:

[image]

No matter how small I make the image (`0.1\textwidth`, `0.01\textwidth` ...) I can't make it appear in the right page. The image goes alone to the next page.

The image is 2506x2014 pixels, so with `0.3\textwidth` and two lines of text under the figure there is plenty of space at the bottom of the page.

If you need any other piece of info about the code please tell me.

---

**Edit:** Uploaded the simplified version of .tex projects with the images (it compiles just fine and skips the image just as before), it can be downloaded here: http://www.mediafire.com/download/uztssz91s9yyyru/latex_test.zip

---

self contained MWE not requiring a download:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % modern style
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{20pt} 

\pagenumbering{alph}
\pagestyle{plain} % page numbers but no headers

\usepackage[hmargin=1.9cm,vmargin=1.9cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}\large

\section{La columna vertebral}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \rule{3cm}{13cm}

  \caption[Columna vertebral adulta] % index text
  {Columna vertebral adulta. 7 vértebras cervicales, 12 torácicas, 5
    lumbares, 5 sacras y las 4 últimas, fusionadas, forman el
    cóccix.} % text under figure
  \label{} % for ref and pageref 
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}

  \textbf{La columna vertebral adulta} tiene curvas en forma de
  S. Está formada por huesos llamados vértebras y por discos
  intervertebrales cartilaginosos. Si las curvas están bien
  estructuradas, la musculatura del tronco trabaja de una manera
  armónica y habitualmente se adoptan posturas correctas, los discos
  intervertebrales están sometidos a una presión adecuada.

En el caso de \textbf{la columna vertebral infantil}, dentro del útero
materno, el feto descansa con la columna vertebral flexionada y las
piernas dobladas. Por ello, al principio, el recién nacido tiene la
columna vertebral doblada hacia delante y no tiene las curvas en S
como el adulto. Poco a poco, se va formando la curvatura lumbar cuando
el bebé yace estirado de espalda sobre una superficie semidura. Más
adelante, cuando se pone en la posición denominada de la esfinge, boca
abajo y apoyado sobre los antebrazos estira la cabeza (ver Fig.5.3),
se va reforzando la musculatura que recubre la columna y se va
formando la curvatura de la zona cervical.

Las curvas en S van alcanzando su mayor desarrollo cuando el niño
empieza a andar y no están bien formadas hasta los cuatro años,
aproximadamente. (Fig. \ref{006}).La forma definitiva de la columna
vertebral se alcanza entre los cinco y los siete años.

\end{multicols}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \rule{2cm}{5cm}

  \caption[Columna vertebral bien formada] % index text
  {Columna vertebral bien formada: A: curva cervical / B: curva
    torácica / C: curva lumbar / D: curva sacra.} % text under figure
  \label{006} % for ref and pageref 
\end{figure}

% New subsection:
\subsection{Principales causas de los problemas de columna}

\textbf{a) Falta de entrenamiento de la musculatura}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \rule{1cm}{1cm}

  \caption[Bebé con el tronco inmovilizado] % index text
  {Es aconsejable tener poco tiempo al bebé con el tronco
    inmovilizado.} % text under figure
  \label{008} % for ref and pageref 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Word of advice: Instead of using the `center` environment, use `\centering`, it does not introduces extra white space. Omit  the optional argument for the `table` and `figure` environments (i.e. `[!htbp]`) and let LaTeX do it's job. you can influence the output when polishing the document at the very end, but not at the writing stage.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks. Tried the suggestion on the three figures of this `\section` (because I assume that the problem has to be enclosed between the two `\clearpage` surrounding this section) and LaTeX did a messy job even placing one figure before the `\section` tag (??) which is not acceptable. I already am at the polishing stage, preparing the document to be printed. I really did not expect this kind of error, i makes no sense to me... there is enough space, I should be able to place it there.

Comment: All we have right now is a screenshot, no code to test. Providing testable code (i.e. a minimal working example) might be quite hard to ge in your case. You can leave out the `figure` environment completely and use package `capt-of` to get a caption.

Comment: Might be an idea to provide the document and the figures for others to download and test.

Comment: @daleif Good idea. I just did that, added the link as an edit to the post. Thanks.

Comment: That is one strange test case (it can be simplified a bit). No idea what is going on.

Comment: @daleif So you agree it "should not" behave the way it does...? About the simplification, I did not want to cut anything that could be relevant, even (specially) in the document header. Any suggestion about what should my next step be? Maybe re-ask the question with more relevant details, so it becomes visible again in tex.stackexchange but now with the code? (I hope this is allowed... or at least tolerated. I really don't have much more options.)

Comment: First I'd figure out the height of the images, such that they can be replaced by `\rule{some width}{some height}`. Then post it directly as an MWE. My guess is some interaction with `multicols`. I've also tested it with the `memoir` class and came to the same result.

Comment: you're just setting the width, but not saying anything about the height.  `width=xxx` modifies *only* the width (graphics companion, example p.31).  if you want to specify only the width, then add `keepaspectratio` to force the height to change as well.  also, regardless of the fact that `\centering` is present elsewhere in the file, the `\begin ... \end` is *inside* the figure "box", so will always add more (usually unwanted) space.

Comment: @daleif I 100% agree: it looks like it has something to do with `multicols` because once you remove this from the code the proportions are more or less the same but the problem disappears. But of course I need the two columns, so that is not an option for me...

Comment: it is a bug in multicol it seems: \@textfloatsheight is not properly managed. Will sort this out further during the day

Comment: @FrankMittelbach That is great news! Thank you very much. Please keep me updated. There is another example of this behavior in my document (although less flagrant and more difficult to post about it), I will test it as well. I am available for any additional info that could help solving the bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug in `multicol` similar to the one recently found about marginpars.  At the end of a page LaTeX's normal output routine resets the variables `\@mparbottom` and `\@textfloatsminheight`. The `multicol` package neglected to do so, thus `\@textfloatsminheight` still contained the height from the here float from the first page --- as a result the available space calculations got off the track.

So the problem only appears when  there is a "here" float on the page where `multicols` starts and another one on the page where it ends.

Try the following fix placed after loading the `multicol` package until I'm able to upload a new version to CTAN (you need version 1.8m for the patch to succeed):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\multi@column@out}
   { \global \@mparbottom \z@}
   { \global \@mparbottom \z@ \global\@textfloatsheight\z@}
   {\typeout{patched}}
   {\ERROR}              % the patch failed for some reason
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Excuse me but I am trying to make this patch work and I haven't succeeded yet, most likely due to my lack of expertise on the matter... I presume this patch goes in the definition section on the top, but I get this error: `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \ERROR `. Otherwise I will wait for the upload. By the way, based on your answer I tried adding some dummy characters before and after the `multicols` and the problem persisted.

Comment: @Tremor: You should put the patch *behind*  `\usepackage{multicol}`

Comment: @Tremor the patch is changing multicol so it has to come after loading that package as Ulrike said. As to "immediately":: not that immediate. The problem is that the first "h" float comes on the page where multicols starts and the second on the page where it ends.

Comment: I am really sorry but I don't seem to be able to make the code work. I tried to follow all your specifications, trying any permutation that I could think of, but every single time LaTeX is telling me that `\ERROR` is not recognized. This was my best guess so far, please correct me if I'm wrong: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=f2GkwnvJ

Comment: @Tremor my guess is that you are trying to patch against an old version of multicol, the patch requires 1.8m or perhaps one version earlier

Comment: @FrankMittelbach That was it, I removed the `multicol.sty` so the package would be automatically re-downloaded, and now the images are placed in the right place. The patch works like a charm, I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

All I can surmise is that the figure can't fit, contrary to your statements in the question.

Like the commenters above say, get rid of `\begin{center}...\end{center}` because it adds additional (and unwanted) vertical space. Here's an example that shows that you should be able to squeeze such an image onto the page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\def\1{text }\def\2{\1\1\1\1\1}\def\3{\2\2\2\2\2}\def\4{\3\3\3\3}
\begin{document}
\4

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\rule{0.25\textheight}{0.3\textheight}
\caption{\3}
\end{figure}

\4

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\rule{0.25\textheight}{0.3\textheight}
\caption{\3 \3}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you want to ensure that it's not the figure placement algorithm that's moving the float, you can insert a non-floating figure in a couple of ways. One is:

```
\usepackage{float}
...
\begin{figure}{H}
```

I *usually* do not recommend this, but if you're in the final stages before publication then it's a lot easier to justify baking in the typesetting decisions like this.

Comment: I tried the `\centering` and it didn't work (in fact the uploaded .tex contains `\centering` already). To me it would be weird that it would be a problem of "I don't have enough space to fit the figure in", because there seems to be space and if I set the image size at `0.01\textwidth` there is no way the figure fits in the blank space at the bottom of the page... of course there is an error somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: everyone, you included, have missed the fact that only the width changes when that is specified.  try specifying `scale` or `height`, which should have a more useful effect.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's what I included the size of the image (2506x2014 pixels) in order to show the proportions. In the document I work with `\textwidth` for practical reasons, but of course I keep in mind the height (which being proportional it is not that much of a hassle). This is also what I was pointing out that making it `0.01\textwidth` didn't even let the image appear in the right place. I agree with Will Robertson that at this point the most likely explanation would be some kind of weird interaction with `multicols`.

Comment: @Tremor -- then try adding `\keepaspectratio` as you decrease the width.  that will preserve the proportions of the image.  if latex "thinks" the image is too tall (which i suspect it is -- i can't easily convert the pixel value to a page dimension), it's going to be forced to a new page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I just tested that and it does not work. Please yourself with the code (see bottom edit in the main question). It really makes no sense. It looks like it has something to do with `multicols` because once you remove this from the code the proportions are more or less the same but the problem disappears. But of course I need the two columns, so that is not an option for me...

Comment: Also a `\clearpage` right after the `multicols` allows them to be on the same page. I think we need David Carlisle to answer this.

Comment: It does fit, and like Tremor I think it has to do with multicols. There seems to be to many floats around it. I would use float and [H] e.g. for the float directly after the section command.

Comment: Thanks for the update to the question. I agree with @UlrikeFischer !

Comment: it is a "h" that triggers the problem in the first place :-), i haven't check but "H" might draw the same conclusions; but it is multicols misbehavior